# Can't get this CSS transition to properly function on an iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I'm currently working on a CSS transition and I'm struggling to find the proper Javascript to make it function properly on a mobile device. 
http://seancrater.com/test/
In the section, "The Dirty Dozen Plus", the transition can be seen. I currently have
    ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');
added to each of the DIVs but it currently requires you to hold down your finger on it from a mobile device to keep it on the transition state. I was wondering if anybody could give me some insight on how to make it a single click to make it stay in the transition state. I tried the pseudo :focus and it stopped it from functioning all together.
Thanks! -Sean

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fswGD/
it isnt really displaying right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, you'll need to avoid :hover.

The easiest way to address your issue is to update your CSS like so:

```
.top:hover,
.top.touched {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-150px);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
```

And then add `touched` as a class to your elements on `touchstart` or `touchend`. My guess is you'll want to maintain which element currently is touched, so you can remove the transitioned state when a user scrolls or touches another element.

(EDIT: Updated fiddle to allow user to tap close the element)
http://jsfiddle.net/4n6Z4/1/

Shell, for easier testing on a smartphone:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/4n6Z4/1/show/

Comment: Any chance you can help me do that? Really struggling to even get the transition to even happen on a smart phone.

Comment: Sure, I can. Let me throw a fiddle together for you!

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rP87K/ - And shell, for easier testing on a smartphone: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rP87K/show/

Comment: An edited fiddle to allow user to tap the element to close transition: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4n6Z4/show/ (slightly better experience :)

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! Literally a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

`ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('click');` There are no hover events in mobile. You need to turn your hover event into a click event for mobile phones. Use javascript to detect if it's a phone or not. Setup a constant `var phone = false` and if it's a phone and set it to true and if not it remains false. Then use it in your function that controls / or triggers that animation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use :hover on mobile.
more info

> As you know, :hover behavior doesn’t exist on touch screen devices. So
>   when you design a responsive website, you should carefully plan when
>   and where to use :hover interactions. Simple links that open some URL
>   will loose their :hover effect on some touch screen devices. On iOS
>   :hover is triggered before the click event, so you will see the hover
>   style for a brief moment before the page changes. Those are minor
>   things, they don’t affect the functionality of the site. The real
>   problem is a :hover  that either hides or shows another element using
>   display or visibility CSS properties. This type of :hover will
>   transform into the double tap behavior on touch screens.

http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/